# Package 'rmongodb' not available for R version 3.5.0

Tags: r, rstudio, rmongodb

I cannot install rmongodb package with RStudio. I have IOs

When I run my app I get

```
Warning: Error in library: there is no package called ‘rmongodb’
51: stop
50: library
```

So I do:

```
install.packages("rmongodb")
```

But I get:

```
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘rmongodb’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)
```

I have also tried:

```
install.packages("rmongodb", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com", dependencies = TRUE)
```

with the same result

Comment: It's been removed from CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmongodb/index.html

Comment: Since, as @RussHyde says, it's been removed from the CRAN repository, in particular you will want to follow option 6 from the top answer to the question I've proposed as a duplicate.

Comment: You could try using `mongolite` instead https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mongolite/index.html